# Why did Edwards use two characteristic functions for each interval in the Riemann sum proof?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

I do not understand why Edwards, in his Advanced Calculus of Serveral
Variables, used two characteristic function $\varphi_{i}$ and $\psi_{i}$
for each interval of the partition $\mathscr{P}_{0}$, in his proof
of the Riemann sum theorem. I see nothing in the preceding theorems
that would explain that. In one example he uses $\varphi_{i}$ for
the characteristic function of the interior of the partition intervals,
and $\psi_{i}$ for the closure of the same interval. He didn't explain
he reason for doing so in that example.

**Would someone, please explain why he would have used two different
characteristic functions for each interval?**

Apparently $\varphi_{i}=\psi_{i}$,
except, perhaps on the boundary of the interval.

This is the first half of the proof, where the characteristic function appear.

> Theorem 3.4: Suppose $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$
>   is bounded and vanishes outside the interval $\mathcal{Q}$. Then
>   $f$ is integrable with $\int f=I$ if and only if, given $\varepsilon>0$,
>   there exists $\delta>0$ such that
>
> $$
> \left|I-\mathcal{R}\left[f,\mathscr{P},\mathscr{S}\right]\right|<\varepsilon
> $$
>
> whenever $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{Q}$ with $\text{Mesh}\left[\mathscr{P}\right]<\delta$
>   and $\mathscr{S}$ is a selection for $\mathscr{P}$.
>
> Proof: If $f$ is integrable, choose $M>0$ such that $\left|f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]\right|\le M$
>   for all $\mathfrak{x}$. By Theorem 3.3 there exist step functions
>   $h$ and $k$ such that $h\le f\le k$ and $\int$$\left(k-h\right)<\varepsilon/2$.
>   By the construction of Theorem 3.2, we may assume that $h$ and $k$
>   are linear combinations of the characteristic functions of the intervals
>   whose closures are the same. That is, there is a partition $\mathscr{P}_{0}$=$\left\{ \mathcal{Q}_{1},\dots,\mathcal{Q}_{s}\right\} $
>   of $\mathcal{Q}$ such that
>
> $$
> h=\sum_{i=1}^{s}a_{i}\varphi_{i}\text{ and }k=\sum_{i=1}^{s}b_{i}\psi_{i},
> $$
>
> where $\mathcal{Q}_{i}$ is the closure of the interval of which $\varphi_{i}$
>   is the characteristic function, and likewise for $\psi_{i}$.
>
> Now let $\mathcal{A}=\mathcal{Q}-\cup_{i=1}^{s}\text{Int}\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]$.
>   Then $v\left[\mathcal{A}\right]=0$, so there exists $\delta>0$ such
>   that, if $\mathscr{P}$ is a partition of $\mathcal{Q}$ with $\text{Mesh}\left[\mathscr{P}\right]<\delta$,
>   then the sum of the volumes of those intervals $P_{1},\dots,P_{k}$
>   of $\mathscr{P}$ which intersect $\mathcal{A}$ is less than $\varepsilon/\left(4M\right)$.
>   Let $P_{k+1},\dots,P_{n}$ be the remaining intervals of
>   $\mathscr{P}$, that is, those which lie interior to the $\mathcal{Q}_{i}$
>   . If $\mathscr{S}\left\{ \mathfrak{x}_{1},\dots,\mathfrak{x}_{n}\right\} $
>   is a selection for $\mathscr{P}$, then $h\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\le f\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\le k\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]$
>   if $i=k+1,\dots,n$, so that
>
> $$
> \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}f\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right]\text{ and }\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\int_{P_{i}}f
> $$
>
> are both between $\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\int_{P_{i}}h$ and $\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\int_{P_{i}}k$,
>   so it follows that
>
> $$
> \left| \sum_{i=k+1}^{n}\int_{P_{i}}f-\sum_{i=k+1}^{n}f\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right] \right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2},\text{(1)}
> $$
>
> because $\int_{\mathcal{Q}}\left(k-h\right)<\varepsilon/2$ by assumption.
>
> Since $-M\le f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]\le M$ for all $\mathfrak{x}$,
>   both
>
> $$
> \sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{P_{i}}f\sum_{i=1}^{k}\text{ and }f\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right]
> $$
>
> lie between $-M\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right]>-\varepsilon/4$
>   and $M\sum_{i=1}^{k}\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right]<\varepsilon/4$,
>   so it follows that
>
> $$
> \left|\sum_{i=1}^{k}\int_{P_{i}}f-\sum_{i=1}^{k}f\left[\mathfrak{x}_{i}\right]\mathit{v}\left[P_{i}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{2}.\text{(2)}
> $$
>
> Since $I=\int f=\sum_{i=1}^{n}\int_{P_{i}}f$ , (1) and (2), finally
>   imply by the triangle inequality that $\left|I-\mathcal{R}\left[f,\mathscr{P},\mathscr{S}\right]\right|<\varepsilon$
>   as desired.

Comment: Why was this question down-voted?  It is clearly state (save a bit of bad grammar).  It is obviously on topic.  The reason for the inclusion of two characteristic functions per interval is not explained by Edwards, and is not obvious.  So it constitutes a good question.  I spent a lot of time writing it up.  To have it down-voted is insulting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Apparently $\varphi_{i}=\psi_{i}$,
>   except, perhaps on the boundary of the interval.

Yes. But they differ on the boundary, then $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ are two different functions and one needs different notations. For instance $1_{(0,1)}$, $1_{[0,1)}$, $1_{[0,1]}$ are three *different* characteristic functions, although they have the same value on $(0,1)$.

In the proof you quoted, note that

> By Theorem 3.3 there exist step functions
>   $h$ and $k$ such that $h\le f\le k$ and $\int$$\left(k-h\right)<\varepsilon/2$. By the construction of Theorem 3.2, we may assume that $h$ and $k$
>   are linear combinations of the characteristic functions of the intervals
>   whose **closures** are the same.

Comment: In the proof he never explains that the $\varepsilon_i$ and $\psi_i$ are defined on the interior and the boundary, respectively.  I am left to speculate about that.  In addition, why it matters to distinguish between interior points of the partition intervals and  the boundaries.  Perhaps it has to do with this (sorry I used different notation here): https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2389616/should-inscirbed-intervals-of-mathbbrn-be-subsets-of-the-interior-of-the-s

Comment: @StevenHatton: He alludes to that at the beginning of section 3 Chapter IV: "the latter may be either open or closed or "half-open"".  "why it matters to distinguish between interior points of the partition intervals and the boundaries"? Because we want to make sure that $h\leq f\leq k$.

Comment: in the second half of the proof he uses they same characteristic function for both $h$ and $k$, So why doesn't it matter there?

Comment: In the first half of the proof, $h$ and $k$ are given by Theorem 3.3, the conclusion of which does not guarantee that $\varphi_i=\psi_i$. In the second half of the proof, $h$ and $k$ are constructed explicitly such that $\varphi_i=\psi_i$.

Comment: Theorem 3.3 and its proof don't mention characteristic functions.  The proof also does not use partitioning.  Theorem 3.2 uses two different characteristic functions because there are two overlapping intervals.  He could, just as well called them $\varphi_1$ and $\varphi_2$.  Also note that he excludes the bounaries of the intervals of $\mathscr {P}_0$ from any application of the step functions, so any distinction between $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ is irrelevant.

Comment: Read the *conclusion* of Theorem 3.3.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/70602/discussion-between-steven-hatton-and-jack).

Comment: The conclusion of Thm 3.3 does not mention characteristic functions *explicitly* but *implicitly*: a "step function" is a linear combination of characteristic functions. See the definition at the beginning of the section.

Comment: Are you saying that he needed two generic characteristic functions because they might be different?  Or am I to understand them to be as in the un-numbered example on page 227?  Is this why he excised the boundaries of the intervals of $\mathscr{P}_0$ in the proof?

Comment: He wants to *use* the conclusion of THM 3.3. ("By Theorem 3.3...") The characteristic functions could be but not necessarily the same.

Comment: OK, I'm catching on a bit.  But the step functions Theorem 3.3 provides don't have to be over the same partition.  I guess I'm supposed to use THM 3.2 to cobble together my $h$ and $k$ over $\mathscr{P}_0$.  But I can't impose closure on the result? Or something like that?

Comment: Yes. Theorem 3.3 gives you the step functions $h$ and $k$ with $h\leq f\leq k$. Theorem 3.2 allows you to assume further properties of $h$ and $k$: "By the construction of Theorem 3.2, we may assume that..."

Comment: Now I am back to confused.  Without further specification, a characteristic function is defined by $$\begin{cases}
\varphi_{\mathcal{A}}\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=1 & \mathfrak{x}\in\mathcal{A}\\
\varphi_{\mathcal{A}}\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]=0 & \mathfrak{x}\notin\mathcal{A}
\end{cases}.$$  So, by definition $\varphi_i = \psi_i$ if they are defined for the same partition, as they are in the proof.

Comment: @StevenHatton: "where $Q_i$ is the *closure* of the interval of which $\varphi_i$ is the characteristic function." So $\varphi_i$ is *not* necessarily the characteristic function of $Q_i$.

Comment: The intervals over which $\varphi_i$  and $\psi_i$ possible have different "closedness" but the same closure.  The characteristic functions are simply define by the intervals themselves.  So, in a sense, there are really two different partitions with the same closure.

Comment: I don't know what confuses you. The partition is given by the $Q_i$'s not the "intervals"; $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ are defined over the "intervals", not the "$Q_i$"'s.