# Why did Edwards define two sets of characteristic functions in this example?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, proof-explanation

**What difference would it have made if Edwards had used the same characteristic
function to define both step functions $h$ and $k$, in the example
below?**

Would it matter if he had used

$$
h=\sum_{i=1}^{p}m_{i}\psi_{i}\text{ and }k=\sum_{i=1}^{p}M_{i}\varphi_{i},
$$

instead?

This question is similar to the [one I asked yesterday](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2574951/why-did-edwards-use-two-characteristic-functions-for-each-interval-in-the-rieman) about Edwards's
proof of the Riemann sum theorem. But in that case he never explicitly
described the boundary values of the characteristic functions.
In this example from page 227 of his Advanced Calculus of Several
Variables, he does explicitly state that the $\varphi_{i}=1$ on the
interiors of the $\mathcal{Q}_{i}$, whereas the $\psi_{i}=1$ on
the closures of the $\mathcal{Q}_{i}$. In this example he is producing
step functions which satisfy the hypotheses of Theorem 3.3:

> **Theorem 3.3** Let $f:\mathbb{R}^{n}\to\mathbb{R}$be a bounded function
>   with bounded support. Then $f$ is integrable if and only if, given
>   $\varepsilon>0$, there exist step functions $h$ and $k$ such that
>
> $$
> h\le f\le k\text{ and }\int\left(k-h\right)<\varepsilon,
> $$
>
> in which case $\int h\le\int f\le\int k$.

This is my rendering of the relevant part of the example from page 227:

Let $\mathcal{Q}\subset\mathbb{R}^{n}$ be a closed interval such
that $f=0$ outside $\mathcal{Q}$. Then the continuous function $f$
on $\mathcal{Q}$ is uniformly continuous. So, given $\varepsilon>0$
there exists $\delta>0$ such that

$$
\left|\mathfrak{x-\mathfrak{y}}\right|<\delta\implies\left|f\left[\mathfrak{x}\right]-f\left[\mathfrak{y}\right]\right|<\frac{\varepsilon}{v\left[\mathcal{Q}\right]}.
$$

Let the set of closed intervals $\mathscr{P}=\left\{ \mathcal{Q}_{i}\right\} _{p}$
be a partition of $\mathcal{Q}$ with $\text{mesh}\left[\mathscr{P}\right]<\delta$.
If

$$
m_{i}=\min\left[f\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]\right],
$$

$$
M_{i}=\max\left[f\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]\right],
$$

$$
\varphi_{i}\left[\text{int}\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]\right]=1\vert\varphi_{i}\left[\not\text{int}\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]\right]=0,
$$

$$
\psi_{i}\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]=1\vert\psi_{i}\left[\not\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]=0,
$$

$$
h=\sum_{i=1}^{p}m_{i}\varphi_{i},
$$

and

$$
k=\sum_{i=1}^{p}M_{i}\psi_{i},
$$

then

$$
h\le f\le k,
$$

and

$$
\int\left(k-h\right)=\sum_{i=1}^{p}\left(M_{i}-m_{i}\right)v\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]<\frac{\varepsilon}{v\left[\mathcal{Q}\right]}\sum_{i=1}^{p}v\left[\mathcal{Q}_{i}\right]=\varepsilon,
$$

so Theorem 3.3 applies.

Comment: "Would it matter if he had used..." you switched $\varphi_i$ and $\psi_i$ in the definition of $h$ and $k$. Is that what you want to ask? If yes, then $h\leq k$ is no longer true.

Comment: Yes.  I should have seen that.